# Homology ring and cohomology ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology

If I have that the cohomology ring of something has $0$ in all odd dimensions and $\mathbb{Z}$ in all even dimensions, and the the ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[x_1, x_2, ..., x_i, ...]$, is it true that the homology ring is the same?  Thanks

Comment: What is the homology ring? (The ring cannot be isomorphic to a polynomial ring in infinitely many variables and be of rank one in even dimensions at the same time, by the way)

Comment: The ring induced by Poincaré duality.  So cap product

Comment: We can assume the space is a closed oriented manifold.

Comment: If we can assume that then add it to the question.

Comment: The cap product is not an operation *inside* the homology but an action of the cohomology on homology, strictly speaking. Also, if the space is a smooth closed manifold, then its cohomology is finitely generated as an abelian group, so it cannot be isomorphic to a polynomial ring